# Inline assembly - pushf without arguments

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, inline-assembly, kvm

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
n = 0;
asm volatile(
    "pushf\n\t"
    "pop %%rax\n\t"
    "or $(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
    "push %%rax\n\t"
    "lea (%%rip),%0\n\t"
    "popf\n\t"
    "and $~(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
    "push %%rax\n\t"
    "popf\n\t"
    : "=g" (start) : : "rax");
```

I'm trying to figure it out by the following pattern:

```
asm ( assembler template,code. 
    : output operands                   (optional)
    : input operands                    (optional)
    : list of clobbered registers       (optional)
    );
```

"pushf\n\t" pushes a value to the stack? what is the value that this command pushes to the stack?
same for "popf\n\t"

basically i want to write a test that simulates data write/read breakpoint.

I attached the code from kvm-unit-test repository:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    unsigned long start;

    setup_idt();
    handle_exception(DB_VECTOR, handle_db);
    handle_exception(BP_VECTOR, handle_bp);

sw_bp:
    asm volatile("int3");
    report("#BP", bp_addr[0] == (unsigned long)&&sw_bp + 1);

    set_dr0(&&hw_bp);
    set_dr7(0x00000402);
hw_bp:
    asm volatile("nop");
    report("hw breakpoint",
           n == 1 &&
           bp_addr[0] == ((unsigned long)&&hw_bp) && dr6[0] == 0xffff0ff1);

    n = 0;
    asm volatile(
        "pushf\n\t"
        "pop %%rax\n\t"
        "or $(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
        "push %%rax\n\t"
        "lea (%%rip),%0\n\t"
        "popf\n\t"
        "and $~(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
        "push %%rax\n\t"
        "popf\n\t"
        : "=g" (start) : : "rax");
    report("single step",
           n == 3 &&
           bp_addr[0] == start+1+6 && dr6[0] == 0xffff4ff0 &&
           bp_addr[1] == start+1+6+1 && dr6[1] == 0xffff4ff0 &&
           bp_addr[2] == start+1+6+1+1 && dr6[2] == 0xffff4ff0);

    n = 0;
    set_dr1((void *)&value);
    set_dr7(0x00d0040a);

    asm volatile(
        "mov $42,%%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%rax,%0\n\t"
        : "=m" (value) : : "rax");
hw_wp:
    report("hw watchpoint",
           n == 1 &&
           bp_addr[0] == ((unsigned long)&&hw_wp) && dr6[0] == 0xffff4ff2);

    return report_summary();
}
```

Comment: The flags, that's what the f means. It's in your manual, right?

Comment: ok, so how can i know what the command pushes to the flags? and which flags is it?

Comment: It pushes the flags (mostly the same way any other register is pushed), not to them. `popf` pops to the flags. Not all flags participate, the VM and RF flags are masked out. That's also in the manual of course

Answer (score 0):

The pattern

```
asm ( assembler template,code. 
    : output operands                   (optional)
    : input operands                    (optional)
    : list of clobbered registers       (optional)
    );
```

is used for [gcc inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

So breaking down the parts in your example first there is the actual assembly code that is executed:

```
"pushf\n\t"
"pop %%rax\n\t"
"or $(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
"push %%rax\n\t"
"lea (%%rip),%0\n\t"
"popf\n\t"
"and $~(1<<8),%%rax\n\t"
"push %%rax\n\t"
"popf\n\t"
```

To see exactly what each of these instructions are doing you should look at an x86 instruction manual.  However, there are a couple of points specific to the extended asm syntax.

In the line `"lea (%%rip),%0\n\t"` the `%0` means that this will be replaced with the first constrain value which will be listed in the `output operands` section.  In this example that is `"=g" (start)`.

The `g` means
["Any register, memory or immediate integer operand is allowed, except for registers that are not general registers."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) and the `(start)` means that the variable `start` in the code will use this value.

In you example the input operands section is empty so the asm code does not get any input values from the earlier C code.

Finally in the list of clobbered registers section the code indicates that `rax` is clobbered.  This means that the compiler should assume that the asm code can change the value of `rax` and so the compiler would need to save/restore the value in `rax` before/after the inline asm code executes, if `rax` was a live register.